# Google actions sdk 2 nodejs response / chat bubble limit

Tags: node.js, google-assistant-sdk

I am using the Google-actions-sdk v2 and trying to build a gaming application. In the documentation it says conv.ask() is limited to 2 responses per turn. So this basically means I can only show 2 chat bubbles then it will not allow me to display more until after user input. But when I look at some other published applications they have many more then 2 in a row displayed. I can't seem to understand or find any info on how they can get around this limitation. 2 seems a unreasonable limit.

For speech you can merge text lines together and it will sound fine, but presentation on screen is awful without being able to break it down to more responses.

Does anyone out there have any insight on this?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, everything in a single line would sound bad. Why don't you try to separate the necessary texts with the help of the SSML library, I recommend it to you.
You can use the break tag to put a pause between each text.

```
<speak>
  I can pause <break time="3s"/>.
  I can pause by second time <break time="3s"/>.
</speak>
```

[Here you have the documentation.](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml)

Now if what you want to give is multiple selection options, you can also use the suggestion chip.

[image: Suggestion Chips]

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#suggestion_chip

Comment: The issue I want addressed is to do with the limitation of a max of 2 bubbles in the visual display for Google assistant. I already know timings can be adjusted, but thanks. I don't believe this would effect the bubble layout?